# Highcharts dynamically add/change yAxis plotLines

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to make it possible for my users to add a max plotLine to a chart and have it change the background color of the chart if a plot goes above that line.  I can't seem to get a method to update the plotlines.  I've tried:

```
chart.yAxis[0].update({
    plotLines: [{
        id: 'limit-max',
        color: 'blue',
        dashStyle: 'LongDashDot',
        width: 1,
        value: 45000,
        zIndex: 0
    }]
});
```

but I get the error:

> TypeError: a is undefined
>
> ...dBands,function(a){a.render()});n(this.series,function(a){a.isDirty=!0})},setCat...
>
> highcharts.js (line 136)

Comment: Since I cant find the code I used I will just leave a comment. Try removing the plotLine then re-adding it with the new value.

Comment: That did the trick - I just didn't start out with one and then used update to add it.

Answer (score 5):

You can only destroy and create new plotLins, because update() function is not available.

Comment: I stripped the plotLines out of the source code and am allowing the user to add it in after the chart is created.

Comment: You can use addPlotLine function to do this.http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.addPlotLine()

Comment: @SebastianBochan - Was this function removed? Can't find it in the docs or Google...

Answer (score 3):

just add this code and then you can use the plotline.update method

```js
    //Add support for update method
    Highcharts.PlotLineOrBand.prototype.update = function (newOptions){
        var plotBand = this;
        Highcharts.extend(plotBand.options, newOptions);
        if (plotBand.svgElem) {
            plotBand.svgElem.destroy();
            plotBand.svgElem = undefined;
            plotBand.render();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks this works great. Just pass in the property you need updated and it will work: `chart.series[0].xAxis.plotLinesAndBands[0].update({ "color": "#eeeeee" });`

Answer (score 1):

Here's what worked for me http://jsfiddle.net/tx1kt0bj/2/

```
var plotBand = tempAxis.plotLinesAndBands[0];

$.extend(plotBand.options, {
    color: '#000',
    to: 10,
    from: 2
});
plotBand.svgElem.destroy();
plotBand.svgElem = undefined;
plotBand.render();
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to assign an id to plotLine,

First remove the plotline completely by `removePlotLine(id)`, then added it back by `addPlotLine`. It works great for me.

```
function upgradePlotLine(new_line) {
    chart.yAxis[0].removePlotLine('my_line');
    chart.yAxis[0].addPlotLine(new_line);
}
```